# Discord bot that blocks some messages

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot that would delete people's messages in a channel if the message is not "test" but I can't find how to do it, can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run `msg.delete()`!

```js
let SPECIFIC_CHANNEL_ID = '1234567890123456';
client.on('message', msg => {
   if (msg.channel.id == SPECIFIC_CHANNEL_ID && msg.content.toLowerCase() != 'test') {
      msg.delete();
   }
});
```

You can get channel id's by turning on developer mode in discord's appearance settings, going to a channel, and right-clicking `Copy ID`